# Как удалить первый элемент односвязного списка?

Tags: односвязный-список, динамические-структуры

Допустим есть список структур. Чтобы удалить не крайний элемент нужно просто в предыдущей структуре адрес на следующий элемент перекинуть на адрес следующего элемента и очистить выброшенный элемент(надеюсь я понятно изъяснился). Но как сделать 2ой элемент первым? Если просто удалить из памяти первый элемент то к списку уже нельзя будет обратиться?

Comment: Обновить значение `HEAD`.

Comment: Что значит HEAD?

Comment: начало односвязного списка

Comment: Я все равно не понимаю к чему это? Если я обновлю значение первый элемент как был так и останется.

Comment: Нет, не останется.

Comment: ничего не нашел на счет обновления head. Что значит обновить?

Comment: Присвоить новое значение. Чтобы оно стало указывать на элемент, который был вторым до удаления первого.

Comment: @DanilaPtuha, HEAD (тут)  это тот указатель, который вы используете для доступа ко всему списку структур (и заодно к его первому элементу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Односвязный список состоит из узлов(Node), в каждом узле есть ссылка на следующий узел. Последний узел указывает на null.

Примерно выглядит вот так:

```
HEAD
 ↓
Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3 ->...-> NodeN -> null
```

Т.к. Второй элемент 'не знает' о существовании первого, то удалить первый элемент очень просто.

```
deleteFirst(List l) {
    // first - первый узел списка aka HEAD
    // поле next - указатель на следующий узел
    l.first = l.first.next;
}
```

И после удаления список будет выглядеть вот так

```
         HEAD
          ↓
Node1 -> Node2 -> Node3 ->...-> NodeN -> null
```

А первый элемент, ссылки на который у нас уже нет, из памяти удалит GC.